# Php's mail double-ing up on new lines

Tags: php, email

For some reason in php when sending a "multipart/alternative" email it seems to double-up new lines messing up the formatting for plain-text clients.

Here's my code:
                            $boundary = uniqid('np');

```
                        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;charset=utf-8;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "From: GamingOnLinux.com Notification <noreply@gamingonlinux.com>\r\n" . "Reply-To: noreply@gamingonlinux.com\r\n";

                        $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
                        $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
                        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
                        $message .= $plain_message;

                        $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
                        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";
                        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
                        $message .= "$html_message";

                         $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

                        // Mail it
                        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So it ends up coming out like this:

```
--np53494d20d247e

Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

When there should be no line between them?

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using MS-Windows style line endings (`\r\n`). Use Unix style line endings instead (`\n`) and most likely your issue is solved.

Different systems traditionally encode line ending different. But the unixoid version is the one which probably can be considered the "internet native style", since the internet (thus all network exchange stuff) was developed based on unixoid systems. Actually things were more complex, this obviously is a simplification. Therefore most (at least all sane) clients like email programs should be able to handle and disply such line ending correctly, whilst the MS-Windows style looks "funny" to many of them.

Comment: Won't that then break it for any kind of Windows client?

Comment: If im not wrong, the \r is unix/mac and \n is windows. Its typically done as a double to make sure its good on both worlds - all clients should ignore the one from the other world.. However, try to use $message .= "your stuff".PHP_EOL; instead of that \r\n stuff. It helped me in some cases, though im not sure if this will fix your problem.

Comment: Have a try, typically not. Consider for example web pages (html markup). They also contain line breaks, unixoid line breaks, especially in text area input fields. Browsers on MS-Windows systems display such content correctly.

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt Sorry, but that is not the case! MS-Windows uses _two_ characters (`\r\n`) whilst unixoid systems use a single character (`\n`). The _old_ Apple systems used (`\n\r`, whyever), but since the introduction of OSX the Apple worls has become more unixoid (again). You can easily test that yourself: create a multi line text file using a normal text editor (not a word processor). Then check the contents with a hexeditor. You will see the line ends.

Comment: Made a quick research. You're right. Learned something new then :) Not the line-break specialist like you are. I was thinking so since using a mac always caused trouble on webdevelopment for windows machines. Had to remove the \r all the time. 

Just learned they use the \r to replace content... e.g. in progress bars in terminal.

"00.00% \r 12.43%"
=> Output: 12.43%

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt Yep, that is _kind of_ true. Actually `\r` is nothing but the "carriage return" the older amongst us still know from typewriters. It places the cursor at the start of the current line again, thus what is printed afterwards is printed _over_ what has been printed before. Thus the replacement. On the other hand `\n` is a classical "line feed", which means jump one line down. On a typewriter (and in printing systems) this does _not_ include the "carriage return", both are separate. That way one could state that the MS-Windows style is "more correct".

Comment: @LiamDawe Careful, that is coincidence! `PHP_EOL` resolves to the line break encoding _native to the server system_! Probably unixoid here. But that is not the right solution, since that has nothing to do with the systems _receiving_ the messages. If the same code was to be run on an MS-Windows style system things would be broken again! Instead you should either hard code `\n` (since it is simply the correct encoding for this), or you should define some global constant as `\n` and use that.